# kendo numerictextbox in clienttemplate - issue with dot in name

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, kendonumerictextbox, kendo-template, client-templates

I am doing following in kendo grid:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.Item.Equity)
    .Format("{0:f2}")
    .Width(100)
    .HeaderTemplate("Equity<br/>Meta")
    .ClientTemplate(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox()
        .Name("mp_#=Item.Id#")
        .Min(0)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { value = "#=Item.Equity#" })
        .ToClientTemplate()
        .ToHtmlString());
```

and get this client template for NumericTextBox:

```
<input class="k-input" id="mp_#=Item.Id#" min="0" name="mp_#=Item.Id#" type="number" value="#=Item.Equity#" /><script>
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("\#mp_#=Item\\.Id#").kendoNumericTextBox({});});
<\/script>
```

Then I have in console: Error: Invalid template

I think that the problem is in

```
jQuery("\#mp_#=Item\\.Id#").kendoNumericTextBox({});
```

because of Item\.Id

Please, can somebody help me to solve the issue with assigning proper name to numerictextbox.

Comment: And what solution you come up with?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen it done like this.  Usually the ClientTemplate is a string of the id of a script block.

This might help: [Can a Kendo Grid Column's ClientTemplate to another kendo object like a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712515/can-a-kendo-grid-columns-clienttemplate-to-another-kendo-object-like-a-listview)